# tvOS custom UITableViewCell with UIView losing background in selected state

Tags: swift, tvos, uitableview

I have simple tvOS application with `UITableView` with custom `UITableViewCell` that have inside UIView. Strange thing is happening when cell is selected (not focused, have to be selected) then UIView is becoming invisible (partially as I discover later by setting border to the `UIView`)
Image below shows the problem:

[image: UIView lose background in selected state]

I tested that when create subclass from `UITableViewCell` and `override func setHighlighted` where I reset background value then `UIView` will be again "visible"

Comment: In the selected state set the background colour of the view again, this happens in iOS as well as tvOS.

Comment: @CW0007007 Is this intentional behaviour (described in documentation?) or some kind of a bug?

Comment: It's internal behaviour, i believe the 'highlight' iOS applies, sets the background colour of views to clear or some sort. I remember this being an issue I had before. I will see if i can find official documentation.

Comment: Thanks, you are right this behaviour is not only limited to tvOS as I thought.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the selected state set the background colour of the view again, this happens in iOS as well as tvOS:

```
- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected;
```

and

```
- (void)setHighlighted:(BOOL)highlighted animated:(BOOL)animated;
```